# Python : call a function with n arguments

Tags: python, function, svg, parameters, arguments

I'm using a function from the `drawSVG` library: `draw.Lines()`. This function is drawing lines between specified points. For example, `draw.Lines(x0, y0, x1, y1)` draw a line between the point (x0, y0) and (x1, y1).

My problem is that I would like to draw n lines. To do that, I need to call the function with n arguments (`draw.Lines(x0, y1, ... xn, yn)`). Each argument must be a number. I have tried using lists and it didn't work.

I didn't find a way to do it properly. Right now I'm calling the function with the right amount of arguments but I do not like that.

For example if I want to print a square

```
svg.append(draw.Lines(10,10,100,10,100,100,10,100))
```

Comment: Can you show the code you would *like* to write - there's sure to be a way to get it to do what you want. For now I'm with @rdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use argument unwrapping to pass a list to a function which expects multiple positional arguments.

Your example can be re-written as:

```
points = [10,10,100,10,100,100,10,100]
svg.append(draw.Lines(*points))
```

So if you have the end-coordinates for your n lines in a list, you can pass that (with a `*`) to the `drawLines` function.